# webpack plugin creation undefined options

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I'm working on building a test webpack plugin.  I have the following code:

```
module.exports = class TestPlugin{
    constructor(options){
        this.options = options;    
    }

    apply(compiler){
        compiler.plugin("emit", function(){
            console.log(this.options);
        })
    }
}
```

in my webpack.config.js file I have the following:

```
const TestPlugin = require('./plugins/TestPlugin');
...  
plugins: [
            new TestPlugin({
                testOption:'testing option'
            }),
...
```

The issue is that it's printing "undefined" instead of the option object.  I put a console.log in the constructor and I get the proper result:

> {testOption:'testing option'}

but I can't seem to access it in the apply method, and it returns undefined.  What am I doing wrong that I can't access this content?  I tried changing "emit" to other things like "done" and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the scope was wrong.  I was trying to access options through "this" inside an internal function changing the scope of "this".  moving it outside of the compiler.plugin function fixed it.

Conversely, changing the

`function(){ ... }`

to

```
() => { ... }
```

also fixes the issue